# strange awk print results when using getline

Tags: awk

I have a text file `file.txt` and have the following context

```
3
7
```

And I found

```
awk 'BEGIN{while((getline i<"file.txt")>0){print i}}'
3
7
awk 'BEGIN{while((getline i<"file.txt")>0){print (i>10)}}'
1
1
awk 'BEGIN{while((getline i<"file.txt")>0){print (i>4)}}'
0
1
awk 'BEGIN{while((getline i<"file.txt")>0){print (i>8)}}'
0
0
```

Why is this strange behavior?

Comment: The strange behavior is the result of >10, which should be the same as the >8 result (and is on my system). Otherwise, awk evaluates whether i is larger than the given value and returns True or False.

Comment: Since you posted a getline loop to demonstrate the issue, can we assume that if you let awk process the input normally (i.e. without getline) you do not see this issue? In other words, does `awk '$0>10'` etc. produce the same results as above or different results? I strongly suspect you just created your file on Windows and so have control-Ms at the end of each line or have some other kind of control characters in the file that's causing awk to treat the input as strings and this whole getline thing is a red herring.

Comment: Run `cat -v file` on your input file and update your question with the result so we can see exactly what's in it. Also, change `print i` to `printf "<%s>\n", i` in your code and update your question with the result of that too.

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations (checked gawk and mawk) convert fields and line to number if possible.. but perhaps yours isn't doing it for getline. In that case:

That's how string comparison works, "3" is bigger than "10":

```
awk 'BEGIN {print ("3">10)}'
1
```

Try to force it to be a number:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print (+"3">10)}'
0
awk 'BEGIN {print (+"11">10)}'
1
```

Comment: So, why is awk using string comparison on the system of the questioner, and numerical on mine and the first person to answer? Teaches me to be explicit, like you demonstrated, to get reliable results.

Comment: It also works with my `awk`. @learning: What awk are you using? Does the `+` solve the problem?

Comment: Your answer is _off topic_, in the question of the OP is no string to discover.

Comment: @captcha: the awk output tells me that in the case of the OP, awk indeed interpreted the fields as strings. Either the OP pasted the wrong results, or OP's awk version works different.

Comment: @dramamezzo if you put `"3"` and `"7"` in `file.txt`, the comparison result is always `0`, as you can see [here](http://pastebin.com/wDhn5jRs).

Comment: @captcha: gawk and mawk converts fields to numbers, if they are numeric. not sure about the other implementations. that's the only explanation I could come up with. I updated my answer. Note: If you put "3" in the file the string is going to be: "`"3"`", not just the string `3`.

Comment: @captcha: Explain to me then how learning gets his/her results for i>10. Until I get confirmation that this is a typo, I interpret learning's question as asking for an explanation of exactly that awk statement - different behavior in different version on different OS is still a possibility. Another possibility could be hidden characters in the text file, that makes awk interpret the input as strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Tested this with [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) 4.1.0 (Windows Version):

```
    $ cat file
    3
    7
    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>10)}}"
    0
    0

    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>9)}}"
    0
    0

    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>8)}}"
    0
    0

    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>7)}}"
    0
    0

    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>6)}}"
    0
    1

    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>5)}}"
    0
    1

    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>4)}}"
    0
    1

    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>3)}}"
    0
    1

    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>2)}}"
    1
    1

    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>1)}}"
    1
    1

    $ awk "BEGIN{while((getline i<\"file\")>0){print (i>0)}}"
    1
    1
```

Normal behaviour.